# How many 5 digit numbers can be formed from 1-8, in which one digit appears only once and 2 other digits appear twice?

Tags: combinatorics

Example : 35573 is such a number while as 33345 is not.

Comment: What have you done on this problem?

Comment: I have no idea where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Pieter21 gave a very good hint.

There are ${{8}\choose{2}} = 28$ ways to  pick the two digits that repeat.

Since each of these two numbers are repeated twice, there is only $5-2\times2= 1$ digit that needs to be chosen out of the $6$ remaining digits. Therefore, there are ${{6}\choose{1}} = 6$ ways to choose the remaining digit.

However, we also need to consider that these numbers may have different orderings (i.e. 33445 and 34345 are different numbers despite having used the same digits.) As a result, there are $5!$ ways to arrange the digits.

We also need to consider that because we have $2$ pairs of the same digit, we need to divide by $2!2!$ to consider the cases that repeat.

Putting all of this together, we have $\dfrac{28\times6\times120}{4} = 5040$ numbers.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail 5−2×2−2×2=1, in either way thank you and Pieter21 for your answers! 5 because 5 digit number, "2x2-2x2" is kind of confusing, shouldn't it be 5-2x2 = 1 ?

Comment: @LendritIbrahimi  yes; sorry, mistake on my part

Comment: Thanks anyway, it think i cleared out how these kind of problems go!

Comment: Another quick question, why do we need to divide them by 2!2!=4? What kind of double counting would that be?

Comment: Let's say that you have a number 22334. If we had a number with all different digits, such as 12345, then one possible permutation would be to switch the first two digits. However, with 22334, switching the first two digits is the same as not switching them at all. Therefore, half of the possibilities are void, since they involve the notion that both of those cases are different. This also applies to the second pair of identical letters.

Answer (score 0):

1. How would you select 2 numbers out of 8?
2. How would you select 1 number out of the remaining 6?
3. How would you reorder these numbers?
4. How would you handle double counting?

Comment: I have no idea, still new to combinations and to be honest my teacher isn't the best one out there so I'm trying to learn on my own, I saw a lot of these kind of problems and the fact that I don't even know how to start is why I asked this question.

Comment: Well, you should still have your textbook, and not start too difficult then. I think I reduced the problem to simpler sub-problems. And if you don't know step 1, then don't continue to this problem yet.

Comment: 1. 8 chose 2 ?Like find the number of subsets of 8?